# ¿Cómo acceder a clases en CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

tengo un sitio hecho con bootstrap 4, a este le integré un formulario que tengo con SalesUp para que recoja los datos. El problema es que quiero ocultar una parte del formulario (el header). Tengo entendido que se puede acceder a clases de la siguiente manera .class1 > .class2 pero no recuerdo bien la sintaxis. Les comparto mis capturas de pantalla.

### 1. Esta es la parte del código que llama un archivo en html que contiene el formulario (esta asi porque al ponerlo directamente, cambia muchos estilos)

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 ml-auto ">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item custom-form" src="contactoSalesForm.html"></iframe>        
</div>
```

### 2. Aquí les muestro un pantallazo de a donde quiero acceder

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### 3. Aquí les muestro como quiero que quede.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe como le podría hacer, podrían ayudarme?

Comment: con añadir en el css `.card-header{display: none}` bastaría para que no te mostrara ese elemento, lo malo es que si lo usas en otra parte del proyecto, tampoco aparecerá por eso es mejor o añadirle un nombre de clase que no lo use ningun otro componente o un id. aunque el principio es el mismo. si es con un id sería `#id{display: none}`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que esas clases ya están definidas, la clase .card-header entre otras se las trae automáticamente de la integración.

Comment: Pero tu puedes añadir css si quieres. en el head puedes añadir la etiqueta `<style></style>` y dentro de ella, añadir el css que quieras.

Comment: Asi es, lo que no puedo hacer es agregar estilo a clases que no veo, ya que es una integración

Comment: No te entiendo la verdad. Entiendo que ese código no está en tu html, pero estás viendo el código que se genera. Puede poner en el head de tu html `<style>.card-header{display: none}</style>`. Así cuando se genere el html añadirá esos estilos

Comment: Si, gracias. es exactamente lo que quise decir, el problema es que no se puede hacer de esa manera. No se porque no agarra los estilos.